# Getting Server IP in controller constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, request, session-variables

I need to use the Server's IP in all of my actions.

when i try and put this in the controller constructor it throws an error:

```
_runningServer = AppConstants.Common.ServerDetect[Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"].Substring(0, 4)];
```

and the reason as i found out is that http context is not yet created.

I tried using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` but it doesnt do the trick.

I am using the server IP in an intranet application as an automatic way for the application to  configure itself in various ways.

**UPDATE:**

Seems that overriding Intialize() is a better solution for my case:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    _runningServer =AppConstants.Common.ServerDetect[System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"].Substring(0, 4)];
}
```

Comment: If you are using this to configure your application, you probably should look into doing this on Application Start and not per request.

Comment: i am using also areas in my mvc app and this initialization i need is only for some common actions from certain controllers.So i think its not full application wide need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Tommy s lead i have found in MSDN documentation that `Initialize()` method might be a better solution than `OnActionExecuting()`:

[MSDN LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

> Initializes data that might not be available when the constructor is
>   called.

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    _runningServer =AppConstants.Common.ServerDetect[System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"].Substring(0, 4)];
}
```

Comment: Awesome - good to know.  Also, you can mark your own answer as accepted in order to close out your question and not have an unanswered question in your history!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the HttpContext does not exist at the time the controller is instantiated.  I would look at overriding the base controller's `OnActionExecuting` method and storing your information there.

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
  public string _runningServer;

  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
      _runningServer = AppConstants.Common.ServerDetect[
        filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables.
        ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"].Substring(0, 4)];
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Now you have set your variable and the httpContext is available at this time.  The _runningServer variable should be available to all of your controller actions.  In order to use this in your controllers, you just need to change the class declaration.

```
public class HomeController : MyBaseController
```

Comment: What if i would override the Initialize() method of the controller? is httpcontext initialized there?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: Perhaps, I have not overrode that method as most examples seem to point to overriding this one.  Try it and let us know how it goes! :)

Comment: I just did and updated my question. It seems also from MSDN documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In alternative to ActionFilter you can Create your own **value provider** that searches the data in *RequestHeaders* and populates the IP Address during the model binding.

Check this for Value providers: [IValueProvider](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/using-value-providers-in-asp.net-4.5.htm)